# How to keep Laravel .env file secure in a public github repo

Tags: laravel, docker, github

In my current workflow, I leave my .env files out of my commits as they contain passwords/secrets etc.  I'm going to start using Docker containers which causes an issue with the .env file: I need to push the .env file as well in order for the container to be created.  However, since the project is public, anybody would be able to see my .env file.  Is there a way to hide that one file when I push it to github but still have it accessible in the build?

Comment: It’s never good idea to commit .env file instead commit env-dist as a template. For docker you can send/pass env variable using -e during docker run.

Comment: OK, I just found out about "docker --env-file list".  However, I'm still not clear about where I would put this file on github so that it's secure from prying eyes in a public repository.

Comment: You don’t put this in git at all.

Comment: I must be misunderstanding the flow then.  (And maybe I wasn't completely clear in my initial question...). My hope is to use an automatic deployment once I push to master.  If I do this, github would somehow need access to the .env file.

Comment: Whatever deployment platform you are using should be able to inject that env variable for you without the need to commit anything explicitly in git.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a `docker secret`, where the `docker-engine` holds the secret and it's injecting it in the containers. Unfortunately, this concept is related to `docker swarm` and can not be used on single host.

Similar to the `docker secret`, `docker-compose` can also manage the secrets, but the approach differs from the `docker secret`. The `docker-compose` do not require the `docker swarm`. For more details how to use docker-compose secrets, check the [following blog](https://pythonspeed.com/articles/build-secrets-docker-compose/).

In any case, you will need to find alternative way to move the secret file from your environment to the deployment servers. One way is to use private repository for the secret files.